# SESSION group_concat_max_len size is not enough, it gives a different error when changing the size

Tags: mysql, concatenation, prepared-statement

So I am making a stored procedure in MySQL that accepts an integer _prof_id. This code is for changing my rows to columns dynamically.
Here is my code

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE Get_Attendance(IN _profID INT)
BEGIN
    SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 18446744073709547520;

    SET @sql = NULL;

    SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(IF(date = ''',
      date,
      ''', status_description, NULL)) AS ',
      date
    )
  ) INTO @sql
      FROM current_att_view;

    SET @sql = CONCAT(
                 'SELECT a.professor_fname, a.professor_lname, ', @sql,  
                  ' FROM professor_tbl m JOIN current_att_view a
                      ON m.professor_id = a.professor_id 
                   WHERE m.professor_id = ', _profID,' Group BY entity_ID');

    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

so I have researched and found out that 18446744073709547520 is the maximum value for the group_concat_max_len and it cannot be unlimited. but when I call the procedure, it gives me an error 
[Mysql Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qqyB.png), which came from the 24th and 25th row of my table [24th and 25th row of table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORZtd.png). There are still plenty of rows to concatenate. What should I do? Or are there any other way in order for me to change the rows to columns dynamically?

so my current_att_view (Which is a created view) structure is [current_att_view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AC5kk.png) and the professor table structure is like this [Professor Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhtp3.png) and I want to generate a query that would make a table structure like this
[Table Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuwNb.png)

When I tried my code for group concat, the output is shown as [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3l1c.png)

Comment: How many distinct dates are there in the view?

Comment: Roughly how many dates do you have per student? (max min avg)

Comment: approximately 90+ per term? because that is an attendance, so every date must be recorded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a guess how a simplified version of your data looks

```
drop table if exists current_att_view,professor_tbl;
create table current_att_view
(attendanceid int auto_increment primary key,
entity_id int,
Professor_id int,
dte date,
status_description varchar(8));

create table professor_tbl
(professor_id int, professor_fname varchar(20), professor_lname varchar(20));

insert into current_att_view (entity_id ,
Professor_id ,
dte ,
status_description) values
(1,1,'2018-01-01','Present'),(1,1,'2018-01-02','Absent'),(1,1,'2018-01-03','Present'),
(2,1,'2018-01-01','Absent'),(2,1,'2018-01-02','Absent'),(2,1,'2018-01-03','Present');

insert into professor_tbl values
(1,'bob','smith'),(2,'fred','jones');

select p.professor_fname,p.professor_lname, dte,status_description
from professor_tbl p
join current_att_view a on a.professor_id = p.professor_id
```

This procedure

```
drop procedure if exists p;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE p(IN _profID INT)
BEGIN
    SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 18446744073709547520;
    #SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1024;

    SET @sql = NULL;

set @sql = (
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT('MAX(IF(dte = ', char(39),dte,char(39), ', status_description , null)) AS ', char(39),dte,char(39))
    )
from current_att_view
);
select length(@sql);

    SET @sql = CONCAT(
                 'SELECT m.professor_lname,m.professor_fname,entity_id ,', @sql,  
                  ' FROM professor_tbl m JOIN current_att_view a
                      ON m.professor_id = a.professor_id 
                   WHERE m.professor_id = ', _profID,' Group BY m.professor_lname,m.professor_fname,entity_id ');

     #set @sql = concat('select ',@sql,' from attendance;');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
     deallocate prepare stmt;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Generates this query

```
SELECT m.name,entity_id ,MAX(IF(dte = '2018-01-01', status_description , null)) AS '2018-01-01',
        MAX(IF(dte = '2018-01-02', status_description , null)) AS '2018-01-02',
        MAX(IF(dte = '2018-01-03', status_description , null)) AS '2018-01-03' 
FROM professor_tbl m 
JOIN current_att_view a  ON m.id = a.professor_id 
WHERE m.id = 1 Group BY m.name, a.entity_ID;
```

Which produces this result (as expected)

```
-----------------+-----------------+-----------+------------+------------+------------+
| professor_lname | professor_fname | entity_id | 2018-01-01 | 2018-01-02 | 2018-01-03 |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------+------------+------------+------------+
| smith           | bob             |         1 | Present    | Absent     | Present    |
| smith           | bob             |         2 | Absent     | Absent     | Present    |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------+------------+------------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

I don't think I can help you any further.

Comment: OMG!! THANK YOU SO MUCH!! HOW FOOLISH OF ME TO FORGET THE SINGLE QUOTATION AFTER THE AS PART T.T Thank you sooo muuuch P.Salmon!! :D

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer more an extended comment.This code works fine for every day in 2016-2017 (albeit very slowly) ie 730 days which seems to be more than you would need. I think this proves there is no group_concat truncation on my 64bit box where max_allowed_packed is default 4194304 at least.

```
drop procedure if exists p;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE p(IN _profID INT)
BEGIN
    SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 18446744073709547520;
    #SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1024;

    SET @sql = NULL;

set @sql = (
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT('MAX(IF(dte = ', char(39),dte,char(39), ', 1, 0)) AS ', char(39),dte,char(39))
    )
from dates
where year(dte) in(2016,2017)
);
/*
    SET @sql = CONCAT(
                 'SELECT a.professor_fname, a.professor_lname, ', @sql,  
                  ' FROM professor_tbl m JOIN current_att_view a
                      ON m.professor_id = a.professor_id 
                   WHERE m.professor_id = ', _profID,' Group BY entity_ID');
*/
     set @sql = concat('select ',@sql,' from dates;');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
     deallocate prepare stmt;
END$$
DELIMITER ;

call p(1);
```

Comment: can you clarify what does the char(39),dte,char(39), ', 1, 0)) AS ', char(39),dte,char(39))) do?

Comment: Char(39) is ascii single quote, Code prints all dates in range as headers and a value of 1 in each column.

Comment: And if I display 111111111111111 there is still no problem.

Comment: Thank you @P.Salmon! When i changed the quotations to char(39) the error became Prepared Statement needs to be re-prepared.. I tried adding 'DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;' after executing, still nothing happened

Comment: I don't like Group BY entity_ID because it's non-standard sql Group BY  a.professor_fname, a.professor_lname would be better (but probably not the main problem).If you are getting nothing returned I would suspect the join is finding nothing - I would debug this statement by getting it to work for a known professor and date and then checking if the prepared statement matches the working statement. As to  Prepared Statement needs to be re-prepared I don't know a solution.

Comment: hey @P.Salmon, i tried to debug my code for group concat and the result is uploaded in my post, can you help me, i am so desperate :(

Comment: Images aren't much use can you add sample data from your view and professor table as text to the question or to sqlfiddle together with text versions of the view and tables (show create view current_att_view),(show create table professor_tbl)